# matrix proof, algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^2+B^2=2(AB-BA)$.

Prove that $A^4+A^2B^2+B^2A^2+B^4=O_{2}$ ; $O_2$ is a null matrix of order $2$.

Any ideas? I tried with Cayley Hamilton and it would remain to prove that $\det(AB-BA)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We work over $\mathbb{C}$. Since $A^2=aI+bA,B^2=cI+dB$, the equation is in the form

$(a+c)I+bA+dB=2(AB-BA)$.

We may assume that $b\not= 0$ or $d\not= 0$. Indeed, if $b=d=0$, then $a=-c$ (cf. the trace), $AB=BA$ and we are done.

We put $A=U+\alpha I,B=V+\beta I$; then $(a+c+b\alpha+d\beta)I+bU+dV=2(UV-VU)$.

Choosing $\alpha,\beta$ s.t. $a+c+b\alpha+d\beta=0$, we obtain

$UV-VU=1/2(bU+dV)$. That implies (it's a standard result valid for any $U,V\in M_n$) that $U,V$ are simultaneously triangularizable and, consequently, $A,B$ too. Clearly, $AB-BA$ is nilpotent and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

From the given condition, we have
$$
(A+iB)(A-iB) = (2-i)(AB-BA).\tag{1}
$$
Take determinants on both sides, we see that $\det(AB-BA)$ must be zero, otherwise the determinant of the LHS of $(1)$ is real but the determinant of the RHS is not.

Thus $AB-BA$ is a $2\times2$ traceless singular matrix. By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, it must be nilpotent. Now the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

Hamilton-Cayley's theorem applied on a $2\times 2$ matrix is:$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}$

$$0 = X^2 - X \Tr X + (\det X) I$$

Set $X = AB - BA$:

$$0 = (AB - BA)^2 - (AB - BA) \Tr (AB - BA) + (\det (AB - BA))I = (AB - BA)^2 + (\det (AB - BA))I $$

Taking the trace yields:

$$0 = \Tr(AB - BA)^2 + 2\det (AB - BA)$$

Using the assumption $A^2 + B^2 = 2(AB - BA)$ we get:

\begin{align}
\Tr(A^2B^2) &= \Tr(2(AB - BA) - B^2)(2(AB - BA) - A^2)\\
&= 4\Tr(AB - BA)^2 - 2\Tr(ABAA) + 2\Tr(BAAA) - 2\Tr(BBAB) + 2\Tr(BBBA) + \Tr(B^2A^2)\\
&= 4\Tr(AB - BA)^2 + \Tr(A^2B^2)
\end{align}

This implies $\Tr(AB - BA)^2 = 0$, so $\det (AB - BA) = 0$.

Therefore:

$$A^2 + A^2B^2 + B^2A^2 + B^4 = (AB - BA)^2 = 0$$